# Couchbase patterns for storing a big amount of records

Tags: nosql, couchbase

There is quiet popular example of Couchbase + Hadoop tandem for log file processing.

Hadoop is used for MapReduce jobs and storing log files, and Couchbase is for storing and querying the results (of Hadoop jobs).

What about if I want to query for specific log file. Hadoop is not good at this. 
What is the best options? Is Couchbase appropriate for kind of usecase or are there any better options? Are there any limitations for this objective in Couchbase?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good option, but you have to remember that Couchbase keeps the keys in memory (this allows the server to be very fast for all operations set/get/delete ...)

So it depends a lot of the number of entries you have globally.

The reason why we often see the couple Hadoop+Couchbase is to let Hadoop deals with the "BigData" itself, use Couchbase to provide fast access to a subset (that could be very large) of this data.